# Extracting the city boundary coordinates from an OpenStreetMap dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, openstreetmap

I have the OpenStreetMap data for a country stored in a dataframe `df`. How can I get the coordinates (which together form a polygon in OSM terminology) of specific cities?

A previous answer on how to access a city give me this code:

```
df.filter(df("tags").getItem("name")==="Baarle-Nassau").show()
```

I have tried to access specifically get the boundary by using

```
df.filter(df("tags").getItem("name")==="Baarle-Nassau" && df("tags").getItem("type")==="boundary").show()
```

But this does not yield what I expect: an array of coordinates.

Comment: Update your question providing a minimal and reproducible example